# C++ nested namespace definitions that begin with ::

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, c++17

In the draft §7.3.1¶1 (n4527), the grammar of namespace definition contains:

> enclosing-namespace-specifier:
>
> > identifier
> >
> > enclosing-namespace-specifier :: identifier

That prevents namespace definitions to have an identifier that begins with '::'

```
namespace d{ namespace e {} }
namespace ::d::e
{
void foo(){}
}
```

Is there any reason for that limitation?

---

**Update:**
The downvote(s) and some of the answers made me realize that I wrote "standard" when I meant "draft" in the very first sentence. In my defense, I did write the document number in the parenthesis. Thus, let me stress that this is a question about the nested namespace definitions feature of C++1z.

Comment: To the person who down voted. I posted a piece of code that does not compile. I checked in the standard and I found the rule that prohibits it. I want to understand the reason behind the rule. Why the down vote?

Comment: This is a guess and not an answer, but it is likely because leading `::` denotes the global namespace. so namespace `foo {namespace ::bar {}}` would either have to stop treating `::` as global or promote bar outside of foo which would be weird...better to dissallow it.

Comment: Did you try **using** keyword before **namespace** keyword? may be it solves the problem.

Comment: And since you know that :: is the nested namespace separator, why would you want to begin a namespace name by a separator??

Comment: That's the same reason why slashes are forbidden in folder and file names

Comment: @galinette It is not the namespace identifier that would begin with '::'. It is the enclosing-namespace-specifier that would begin with '::'. After all, a nested-name-specifier can begin with '::'

Comment: @galinette but slashes are not forbidden in paths.

Answer (score 1):

The two uses of `A::` below are very different:

```
void f();
namespace A {
  void f();
  namespace B {
    void f();
    void g() {
      A::f();      // #1
      ::f();
    }
  }
}
namespace A::N {}  // #2
namespace /*::*/N {}
```

1. This *selects* a namespace, to avoid the `B::f` found by unqualified lookup.  This use case applies to the global namespace as well, necessitating `::f;`.
2. This *establishes* (that is, creates or re-opens) a namespace.  This use case obviously does not apply to the global namespace, and so there is no reason to allow `::N` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

A line that starts with `::` indicates to the compiler that you wish to use the global namespace. For example:

```
void foo()
{
  std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

namespace d
{
  void foo()
  {
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
  }

  void example()
  {
    foo();
    ::foo();
  }
}
```

This code will print out:

```
2
1
```

as the first call goes to `d::foo()` and the second goes to the `foo()` in the global namespace. As such, putting a `::` at the beginning of the namespace would make it seem that you are putting `d` in the global namespace, when you are trying to create a namespace for it, which doesn't really make any sense.